# MyViewHolder com erro

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Estou estudando sobre **RecyclerView** mas quando tento executar o código ele ta um erro estranho.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
  at br.com.danilo.concurso.adapter.ConcursoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ConcursoAdapter.java:32)
 at br.com.danilo.concurso.adapter.ConcursoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ConcursoAdapter.java:19)
```

procurei no google, mas só achei respostas genericas.
Caso precisem ver algum arquivo me avise

ps: estou implementando o RecyclerView em uma fragment e os dados delas estão vindo de uma classe separada que retorna um `List<Concurso>`

**ConcursoAdapter.java**

```
package br.com.danilo.concurso.adapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import br.com.danilo.concurso.R;
import br.com.danilo.concurso.model.Concurso;
/**
  * Created by danil on 21/04/2017.
*/
public class ConcursoAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConcursoAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private List<Concurso> mList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public ConcursoAdapter(Context context, List<Concurso> concursos){
    mList = concursos;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
//CHAMANDO SÒ QUANDO SE TEM A NECESSIDADE DE CRIAR UMA NOVA VIEW
// estado de DURTIN
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //CONSTRUCAO PESADA
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}
//CHAMADO TODA HORA
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titulo.setText(mList.get(position).getNome());
    holder.subtitulo.setText(mList.get(position).getSituacao());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public void addListItem(Concurso concurso, int position){
    mList.add(concurso);
    notifyItemInserted(position);

}
//CONSTRUCAO PESADA
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView titulo;
    public TextView subtitulo;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_titulo);
        subtitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_subtitulo);
    }
}
}
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"/>
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="Concurso IRPF 2017"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_titulo"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_titulo"
    android:id="@+id/text_subtitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="40 vagas"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/situacao"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="12sp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_titulo"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_subtitulo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view_divisor" />
<view
    android:id="@+id/view_divisor"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_subtitulo"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.8dp" />
```

O que eu tive que mudar no Layout para ele funcionar

```
...<View
    android:id="@+id/view_divisor"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.8dp" />...
```

Comment: Posta o código do seu Adapter, pois não tem como saber o que causa o erro sem ver o código.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira adicionei o código

Comment: Verifique se existe algum erro no layout *item_list.xml*.

Comment: Como o amigo acima falou, o problema parece estar no layout. Checa se os ID's no layout batem com o que você usou como parâmetro nos findViewById do ViewHolder.

Comment: aparentemente meu *item_list.xml* está ok, vou colocar ele no post para vocês avaliarem.

Comment: rodando o debug eu percebi que ele trava na linha * View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);*  então ele nem chega a chamar o *findviewbyid()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro não tem nada de estranho. Alias, é muito esclarecedor.

Ele diz que na linha 43 do layout, ao tentar comparar um valor nulo, encontra um erro. Portanto, aponta para o local e descreve o problema.

A questão está, no que aparenta ser um separador no final do layout.

Examinando o seu código, só tenho duvidas quanto à linha:

```
 android:layout_height="0.8dp"
```

Não sei se é possível usar menos que `1dp`

Minha sugestão: elimine esta view e seja se funciona. Quando estiver em ordem, coloque um separador, se ainda achar necessário.

Neste caso, use `DividerItemDecoration` Veja na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html)

EDIÇÃO: como o AP mesmo percebeu (e eu não), a questão toda era o fato da `view` começar com maiuscula e no código estar miniscula.

```
<view <-- ERRADO

<View <-- CORRETO
```

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar com o erro, deixei isso passar. Acabei mudando para outro view (deixei no post) mas também vou ler sobre o que falou.